# Bootstrap: Add space between two buttons only if viewport is 'xs'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

My two submit buttons look good when the viewport is 'sm' or larger as this picture shows:

[image: buttons good on 'sm' viewport or larger]

However: as this image shows, when the viewport is 'xs', the buttons get squished together:

[image: 'xs' view]

I'd like to add some space in between the two buttons only when the viewport is size 'xs'.  Without a conditional that checks viewport size: Adding two `<br>` tags would fix the spacing within the mobile view, but would cause problems in all the other viewport sizes since there would then be too much space in those other viewports.

How can I check on the viewport size?  I am open to other suggestions if there is a better solution.

Code for the buttons:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class=" col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2">
      <%= f.button('Search', class: "btn btn-default") %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <%= link_to('Find All Providers', "#", class: "btn btn-default") %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the buttons in `<p>` tags:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class=" col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2">
        <p>
            <%= f.button('Search', class: "btn btn-default") %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p>
            <%= link_to('Find All Providers', "#", class: "btn btn-default") %>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```